# Tibco Spotfire - Issue with text functions

Tags: case, spotfire

I have a column that is prefixed with `OIR$` then a last name. How do I get rid of the `OIR$`?

I've tried using `RIGHT()` but the names are of different lengths, so if I use `Right([column.name], 10)` then I will get some names correct and others will still have the unwanted letters of `OIR$`.

Comment: Thanks for your input...but I found a work around

Mid([column.name], Find("$", [column.name]) +1, Len([column.name])).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
SUBSTRING([column], 5, LEN([column]))

RIGHT([column], LEN([column]) - CHARINDEX('$', [column]))

REPLACE([column], 'OIR$', '')
```

e.g.

```
declare @x varchar(20);
SELECT @x = 'OIR$testing';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@x, 5, LEN(@x))
testing

SELECT RIGHT(@x, LEN(@x) - CHARINDEX('$', @x))
testing

SELECT REPLACE(@x, 'OIR$', '')
testing
```

EDIT: It's not SQL. Maybe https://docs.tibco.com/pub//spotfire/5.5.0-march-2013/UsersGuide/ncfe/ncfe_text_functions.htm

```
RXReplace([column], "OIR$", "", "")
Mid([column], 5, Len(column))
```

Comment: I used REPLACE([column], 'OIR$', '') but it says that "Invalid type for function call RXReplace"....I tried the other two but The program im using(Spotfire) does recognize all functions including substring and charindex

Comment: @3piecechickendinner Oh. Maybe next time say what language you're using in your question or tags, eh? From some random google documentation, RXReplace needs four parameters. How about `RXReplace([column], "OIR$", "", "")` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @x varchar(20);
SELECT @x = 'OIR$testing';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@x, 5, LEN(@x))
testing

SELECT RIGHT(@x, LEN(@x) - CHARINDEX('$', @x))
testing

SELECT REPLACE(@x, 'OIR$', '')
testingd
```